# How to selectively trim an NSMutableString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, substring, nsmutablestring

I would like to know how to selectively trim an NSMutableString. For example, if my string is "MobileSafari_2011-09-10-155814_Jareds-iPhone.plist", how would I **programatically** trim off everything except the word "MobileSafari"?

**Note :** Given the term **programatically** above, I expect the solution to work even if the word "MobileSafari" is changed to "Youtube"  for example, or the word "Jared's-iPhone" is changed to "Angela's-iPhone".

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: On a generic level, what would be the condition that you want your string trimmed? e.g you need to extract the first 20 characters, you want to delete everything except the first 20 characters, etc

Comment: This may be a little vague, but I want to keep all characters of the string until the first underscore, and delete the remaining characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TESTED CODE: 100% WORKS**

```
NSString *inputString=@"MobileSafari_2011-09-10-155814_Jareds-iPhone.plist";

NSArray *array= [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];

if ([array count]>0) {

    NSString *resultedString=[array objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@" resultedString IS - %@",resultedString);



}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
resultedString IS - MobileSafari
```

Comment: It's a bit weird that the accepted answer uses NSString instead of NSMutableString. I was looking for trimming a NSMutableString, but this answer doesn't really answer that.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you always need to extract the character upto the first underscore; use the following method;

```
NSArray *stringParts = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
```

The first object in the array would be the extracted part you need I would think.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format of the string is always like that, it can be easy.

Just use NSString's `componentsSeparatedByString:` documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a).

In your case you could do this:

```
NSString *source = @"MobileSafari_2011-09-10-155814_Jareds-iPhone.plist";

NSArray *seperatedSubStrings = [source componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];

NSString *result = [seperatedSubStrings objectAtIndex:0];
```

`@"MobileSafari"` would be at index 0, `@"2011-09-10-155814"` at index 1, and `@"Jareds-iPhone.plist"` and at index 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
NSString *strComplete = @"MobileSafari_2011-09-10-155814_Jareds-iPhone.plist";  
NSArray *arr = [strComplete componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];  
NSString *str1 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *str2 = [arr objectAtIndex:1];  
NSString *str3 = [arr objectAtIndex:2];
```

**str1** is the required string.
Even if you change **MobileSafari** to **youtube** it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll need an NSString variable that'll hold the beginning of the string you want to truncate. After that one way could be to change the string and the variable string values at the simultanously. Say, teh Variable string was "Youtube" not it is changed to "MobileSafari" then the mutable string string should change from "MobileSafari_....." to "YouTube_......". And then you can get the variable strings length and used the following code to truncate the the mutable string.

```
NSString *beginningOfTheStr;
.....
theMutableStr=[theMutableStr substringToIndex:[beginningOfTheStrlength-1]];
```

See if tis works for you.