# remove characters from NSString when found first comma

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a one `NSString` & I want to remove some characters from it, when the first comma is found in it.

```
ex. str = @"0,1,2,3"; 
output - > str = @"1,2,3";
```

How to do this. Can anyone help me please to sort out this issue.

Comment: I would use the methods you can find here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-SW5

Comment: Please check my answer and comment, its almost similar to your previous questin with 2 strings..

Comment: @Girish Why don't you make the effort reading the documentation and trying to come up with something useful? This is a trivial task...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to selectively trim an NSMutableString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370454/how-to-selectively-trim-an-nsmutablestring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic case:

```
NSString* str= @"0,1,2,3";
NSRange range= [str rangeOfString: @","];
if(range.location!=NSNotFound)
{
    str= [str substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(range.location+1, str.length-range.length-1)];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

It doesn't create a crash if the string hasn't a comma.

Answer (score 6):

Check with the below code:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
if([tempArray count] > 0)
{
   [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
NSString *output=[tempArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: Isn't said that the array count is greater than zero in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
if ([arr1 count]){
    [arr1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
NSString *finalStr = [arr1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
NSString *str1=@"0,1,2,3";
NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
if([arr1 count]>1)[arr1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];//as 1st comma is found. means atleast 2 elements must be there.
NSString *finalString=[arr1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

NOTE:This one not compiled and checked..I just typed in notepad in windows.